# Change the tick color in MuiCheckbox material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't seem to find a way to change the tick color in Material UI [MuiCheckbox](https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/)

All the Demos show how to change the color of the whole checkbox, but in all of them, the tick is white.

How can I change the color of the tick only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is an approach that seems to work. The gist of the approach is to create a box (via the `:after` pseudo-element) that is slightly smaller than the icon for the check and has the desired color as the background color. Then place that box behind the "checked" icon.

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

const CheckboxWithGreenCheck = withStyles({
  root: {
    "&$checked": {
      "& .MuiIconButton-label": {
        position: "relative",
        zIndex: 0
      },
      "& .MuiIconButton-label:after": {
        content: '""',
        left: 4,
        top: 4,
        height: 15,
        width: 15,
        position: "absolute",
        backgroundColor: "lightgreen",
        zIndex: -1
      }
    }
  },
  checked: {}
})(Checkbox);

export default function CheckboxLabels() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedA: true,
    checkedB: false
  });

  const handleChange = name => event => {
    setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <CheckboxWithGreenCheck
            checked={state.checkedA}
            onChange={handleChange("checkedA")}
            value="checkedA"
            color="primary"
          />
        }
        label="Custom check color"
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Checkbox custom check color]

An alternative approach would be to create a custom icon that includes the desired color for the check and then use it via the `checkedIcon` property as in the [Custom icon example](https://material-ui.com/components/checkboxes/#checkboxes) in the demos.

Comment: That sums it all up, thank you for giving more than one option and for the clarity of the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to change the tick color you have to use the following technique. It's an enhanced version of @Ryan above.

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

const CheckboxWithGreenCheck = withStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      fill: "white",
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "white"
      }
    },
    "&$checked": {
      "& .MuiIconButton-label": {
        position: "relative",
        zIndex: 0,
        border: "1px solid #bbbbbb",
        borderRadius: 3
      },
      "& .MuiIconButton-label:after": {
        content: '""',
        left: 4,
        top: 4,
        height: 15,
        width: 15,
        position: "absolute",
        backgroundColor: "green",
        zIndex: -1,
        borderColor: "transparent"
      }
    },
    "&:not($checked) .MuiIconButton-label": {
      position: "relative",
      zIndex: 0,
      border: "1px solid #bbbbbb",
      borderRadius: 3
    },
    "&:not($checked) .MuiIconButton-label:after": {
      content: '""',
      left: 4,
      top: 4,
      height: 15,
      width: 15,
      position: "absolute",
      backgroundColor: "white",
      zIndex: -1,
      borderColor: "transparent"
    }
  },
  checked: {}
})(Checkbox);

export default function CheckboxLabels() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedA: true,
    checkedB: false
  });

  const handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
    setState({ ...state, [name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={
          <CheckboxWithGreenCheck
            checked={state.checkedA}
            onChange={handleChange("checkedA")}
            value="checkedA"
          />
        }
        label="Custom check color"
      />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-custom-check-color-forked-k3kw2?file=/demo.js

Answer (score -1):

There is actually no color settings for the tick. It takes the color of the background by default.

You can wrap your checkbox in a div, put a background color on this `div` and the tick should be colored.

Comment: Can you please give me a code sample with MuiCheckbox? With label

Comment: Wrapping the checkbox in a div puts the color on too big of an area -- it colors the area around the checkbox icon in addition to the tick.