# How to customize Autocomplete tag - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using autocomplete of material ui and this is what default tag looks like

[image]

I want to customize tag like this.

[image]

How can i do that? Thank you.

```
            <Autocomplete
              disableCloseOnSelect={true}
              multiple
              options={this.options}
              getOptionLabel={options => options.title}
              value={this.state.value}
              onChange={(e, techs) => {
                this.newValue(techs);
              }}
              renderInput={params => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant="outlined"
                  placeholder={Technology}
                  fullWidth
                />
              )}
            ></Autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `tag` [CSS class](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#css) to customize the tags as shown below.

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const CustomAutocomplete = withStyles({
  tag: {
    backgroundColor: "#a0a",
    height: 24,
    position: "relative",
    zIndex: 0,
    "& .MuiChip-label": {
      color: "#fff"
    },
    "& .MuiChip-deleteIcon": {
      color: "red"
    },
    "&:after": {
      content: '""',
      right: 10,
      top: 6,
      height: 12,
      width: 12,
      position: "absolute",
      backgroundColor: "white",
      zIndex: -1
    }
  }
})(Autocomplete);

export default function Tags() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: 500 }}>
      <CustomAutocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-standard"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="standard"
            label="Multiple values"
            placeholder="Favorites"
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}


// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
// ... plus many more
];
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: Not bad, but i think this gonna override all tag element in component.

Comment: Yes. Are you wanting each Chip to be styled differently? If so, based on what?

Comment: No, but  my component have more than one autocomplete so i think this is not really good. I trying to use Shorthand class of material ui but it's hard to access span element of Chip.
```

Comment: const CustomizeAutocomplete = withStyles({
  root: {
    
  },
  tag: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  '& + .MuiChip-label': {
    "& span": {
      color: 'white'
    }
  }
})(Autocomplete)

Comment: @randomguy I've updated my example to show how to target the elements within the tag.

Comment: one more question. Can i set color ' x ' in delete icon to white? Like my image above

Comment: @randomguy It is possible, but a little complicated. You need to set the background color, but you can't do it for the whole icon or you will have white in the corners of the square that the circle icon resides in. You should be able to use the same approach from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57970631/change-the-tick-color-in-muicheckbox-material-ui/57982412#57982412.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 27):

The `renderTags` prop from the Autocomplete API docs: https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/

The "tags" are Material UI `Chips` https://material-ui.com/components/chips/
so you can style an individual Chip component or variants to your liking and then override the default tags for Autocomplete.

Your styling for the chip would look something like

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';

export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    color: labelColor,
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
    border: '1px solid',
    borderColor: '#bddaff',
  }
}));
;

const MyChip = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
      <Chip
        className={classes.root}
        {...props}
      />
  );
};
```

And then you override the default chips

```
  <Autocomplete
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
    label
    placeHolder
    multiple
    openOnFocus
    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={label} placeholder={placeHolder} />}
    renderTags={(tagValue, getTagProps) => {
      return tagValue.map((option, index) => (
        <MyChip {...getTagProps({ index })} label={option.title} />
      ));
    }}
    {...rest}
  />
);
```